# Convert Delimited TXT to XLS with OpenText in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to convert delimited txt into xls file. I have come up with 2 very simple line of commands which I suppose should work but in reality it didn't. Can anyone tell me what mistakes I have made?

If this work, I am going to loop it with dir for 3000 txt files...

Thanks!

Bosco

```
Sub ConvertDelimitedTXTtoXLS()
    Dim wb As Workbooks
    wb.OpenText Filename:="C:\Users\boscotsin\Desktop\test0.txt", DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
    wb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\boscotsin\Desktop\success.xls"
End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean does not work?

Comment: run time error, it says the SaveAs command cannot find the method or data

Comment: sorry might be bad translation... my excel in my home computer is in traditional chinese...

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub delimitedTXTtoXLS()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Workbooks.OpenText filename:="C:\Users\boscotsin\Desktop\test0.txt", origin:=xlMSDOS, DataType:=xlDelimited, Tab:=True
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    wb.SaveAs filename:="C:\Users\boscotsin\Desktop\success.xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello John but it says run time error 1004 as I go to the third line... Any ideas???

Comment: Did you change the path and file name to your delimited file?  "C:\Files\Delimited_File.txt" is valid on my machine.  You must change that to the path and file on your machine.  It must be a valid path and file for this to work.

Comment: I've edited the answer to include YOUR path and filenames.  If it doesn't work then it must be a bad path or file name.  Check it again.  Also, you can no longer save in .xls format from vba- it must be .xlsx

Comment: I want to retract that.  I found the filetype to save as an .xls file.  It's in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
' Excel8

Sub delimitedTXTtoXLS2()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Workbooks.OpenText FileName:="C:\Users\boscotsin\Desktop\test0.txt", origin:=xlMSDOS, DataType:=xlDelimited ', Comma:=True
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    wb.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Users\boscotsin\Desktop\success.xlsx", FileFormat:=56, CreateBackup:=False
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```